# Magento2: Images are not shown on second website

Tags: magento2, cache, multistore

I've created a second website, with separate store and store view, where i wish to show only some of the products of the main website.
I'm having some problem with images, even tho not consistently.

When I assign the product to the second store as well the images are not loaded and I can see only the default Magento Image.
On the main website the image continues to load normally, this happens most of the time, but not all the time.

I've checked and i can tell for sure that this is a problem of cache, looking at the image url i can see that in the second store in using a path that doesn't exist. Creating the folder and filling it with the same images of the "regular" path makes them visible. Of course this can only be a temporary solution, since a refresh of cache deletes the folder.
So I've come to think that there's some options that I've not checked with redirect or something.

Just to be complete, se second website use the same domain (so i have website.com/default and website.com/second)